# iOS SDK Time stamp of photo clicked by camera device

Tags: ios, iphone

Just wondering can we get Time stamp of photo clicked by camera of iOS device using iOS SDK?
I've checked here on SO could not find any reference but if i check native PHOTOS app in iPhone photos are grouped by Date. So i wonder there should be a way to get time of photo clicked.

Comment: See here.  Not sure whether to call this a dup, but a good answer here anyway:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read how to retrieve `ALAsset` s.

> An ALAsset represents a photo or a video managed by the Photos
>   application.

And then call

```
NSDate *date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
```

to receive last modification date. [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030384/alassetpropertydate-returns-wrong-date)

To take creation date from Exif use:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter new] autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"y:MM:dd HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[[[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata] objectForKey:@"{Exif}"] objectForKey:@"DateTimeOriginal"]];
```